# At Which Position MD5-PADDING starts?

Tags: md5, padding

I'm trying to implement MD5 File-Hash in and I think it will be finished in the near future. Currently I need to append the PADDING but i don't understand how this works.

Example: I have a file with 109 Bytes of data.

```
//    512 Bit            360 Bit      
//  -------------     -------------    
//  |xxxxxxxxxxx|     |xxxxxx     |     
//  -------------     -------------
```

When appending the PADDING to the data, does it have to look like this:

```
//    512 Bit            360 Bit           512 Bit
//  -------------     -------------     ------------- 
//  |xxxxxxxxxxx|     |xxxxxx|1|00|     |00000000|64|
//  -------------     -------------     -------------
```

or this

```
//    512 Bit            512 Bit      
//  -------------     -------------    
//  |xxxxxxxxxxx|     |xxx|1|00|64|     
//  -------------     -------------
```

or this?

```
//    512 Bit            360 Bit           512 Bit
//  -------------     -------------     ------------- 
//  |xxxxxxxxxxx|     |xxxxxx     |     |10000000|64|
//  -------------     -------------     -------------
```

I'm confused. After Consulting the RFC1321 Text I think to use the Padding in the SAME Block if it is possible to pad inside a block. And if this doesn't fit then use a new block.

Am I right?

EDIT: Need more detail.

Where will the padding be appended?
after the last data bit or the last data byte? or is this the same?

Like this?

```
                512 Bit-Block
--------------------------------------------------
|1|1|0|X0000000|                 |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|

|0|0|0|00000000|                 |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
|0|0|4|00000000|                 |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|
|0|0|6|00000000|    ...          |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|
|1|1|8|00000000|                 |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|
|1|1|0|00000000|                 |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|
|0|1|0|00000000|                 |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|
|1|1|0|00000000|                 |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
--------------------------------------------------  
|DATA |PADDING                   | 64 Bit counter|
```

or like this?

```
                512 Bit-Block
--------------------------------------------------
|1|1|0|00000000|                 |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|
|0|0|0|00000000|                 |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
|0|0|4|00000000|                 |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|
|0|0|6|00000000|    ...          |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|
|1|1|8|00000000|                 |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|
|1|1|X|00000000|                 |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|
|0|1|0|00000000|                 |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|
|1|1|0|00000000|                 |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
--------------------------------------------------  
|DATA |PADDING                   | 64 Bit counter|
```

Comment: "I'm trying to implement MD5 File-Hash", why? There must be hundreds of battle tested implementations out there already.

Comment: "why?" Because of learning how cryptographic hash functions works in detail.

Comment: Why are you struggling with this? Go have a look at OpenSSL's implementation. It's opensource and easy to read (although the docs are horrible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RFC is well defined for this point:

> The message is "padded" (extended) so that its length (in bits) is
>      congruent to 448, modulo 512. [...] In all, at
>      least one bit and at most 512 bits are appended.

So basically, before adding the length, your last block must be 448 bits long. So if you have 109 bytes of data, 872 bits, you need to append 88 bits to the last block:

```
//    512 Bits           512 Bits     
//  -------------     -------------    
//  |xxxxxxxxxxx|     |xxxxxx10064|     
//  -------------     -------------
```

Where `100` is in fact a single `1` bit followed by 87 `0` bit, and `64` is the length of the original message (`872` in your case).

If your message was something like `960` bits long (`512 + 448`), then you would have added a whole `512` bits block (one `1` and 511 `0`), if it was `959` bits long (`512 + 447`), then only a single `1` bit should have been added. These are the two extreme cases.

*Note: Maybe you don't know what [congruent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html) mean and it is what you were struggling to understand the RFC: `X` is congruent to `Y` modulo `Z` if `X % Z == Y`.*

Comment: Thx 4 your post. Now, I understand. It wasn't the fact that i didn't know what congruent means ;) . It was the sentence in RFC: "In all, at least one bit and at most 512 bits are appended." I didnt know what "at least one bit" means.